# 3D Text for mountain peak flyover (Drone shot) not sticking to camera track

Tags: video-editor, davinci-resolve, tracking

I am trying to "pin" a 3D title to a mountain peak while I have a drone shot flyover.

From tutorials I've gotten into the following.

Creating a camera tracker, tracking the scene and solving the tracking. (0.1pxels)

I have my 3D text in the 3D scene, and it makes sense (layout wise) in the 3D scene.

My problem is that my title does not "stick" to the tracking points... As my drone moves over the peak, the title also pushes back. I want to title to stay put , locked to that point of the peak, and get bigger and eventually drop out as I "fly" over it.

In the 3D scene everything looks good but the camera never flies "through/over" the text, and that is obviously why my output is also not rendering properly.

What am I missing? In the pic below, my camera is tracking over/passed the 3D text, but the media out does not reflect this.

[image: Resolve Text clip]

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-4J3e4XcLI